# Appending div to document on click not working, why so?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a button that upon click it creates a div with said height and width onto the document. The div will have random position by giving a random number to div.style.left and div.style.top. It isn't working, can you let me know why? I'd be really grateful. Thank you.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>

    </head>


    <body>

    <button id = "button" onclick = "addMonster()">add monster</button>
    <div id = "square">
    </div>

    <style>
    #square {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 2px solid black;
      font-size:20px;
      color: black;
      position:absolute;
      left: 50px;   
      top: 80px;
    }


    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }



    </style>
    <script>

    var monster = {
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    top: 0,
    left: 0
    };

    function addMonster() {
    monster.height = 100;
    monster.width = 100;
    monster.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    monster.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    div.style.width = monster.width + "px";
    div.style.height = monster.height + "px";
    div.style.left = monster.left + "px";
    div.style.top = monster.top + "px";
    div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    div.style.border = 2px solid red;
    div.innerHTML = "hello";
    };





    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Use the browser console for debugging. You have sytax error

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is causing your code to break.

```
div.style.border = 2px solid red;
```

it should be

```
div.style.border = "2px solid red";
```

P.S : Always check the developer console for errors, issues like undefined variables, unexpected identifiers can be easily debug using it.

```js
var monster = {
  height: 0,
  width: 0,
  top: 0,
  left: 0
};

function addMonster() {
  monster.height = 100;
  monster.width = 100;
  monster.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  monster.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  
  
  
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  div.style.width = monster.width + "px";
  div.style.height = monster.height + "px";
  div.style.left = monster.left + "px";
  div.style.top = monster.top + "px";
  div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  div.style.border = "2px solid red";
  div.innerHTML = "hello";


};
```

```css
#square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 80px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

</head>


<body>

  <button id="button" onclick="addMonster()">add monster</button>
  <div id="square">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code that is preventing your `addMonster()` method from being defined.

Surround `2px solid red` in quotes, and things should work as expected.

I suggest you learn to use the developer console in your browser, this could help you to pinpoint bugs like this easily.  Good luck!